# Objects showing in a different position in XIB compared to iPhone (Screenshot Included)

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, xib

I have several objects such as rectangle buttons, switches, UIlabels etc on my view, however they seem to be showing 5mm below which I have set it as. It's hard to explain so I have created a screenshot of both XIB view and iPhone view.

So in this case, focus on the 'Start' text. Which is set at the correct position in interface builder, but has decided to move 'down' on the iPhone.

Sorry for blurring most of the screenshot out as its a private project.

But the objects should show where they are set on XIB, the same on the iPhone.

iPhone screenshot:

[image: Image 1 of iPhone Screenshot]

XIB ( Interface Builder screenshot

[image: Xib Screenshot]

I've tried remove the status bar on the XIB view, however the problem still persists.

Please join the http, when looking at the image. i cannot post images because i haven't got 10 reps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you've set the wrong autoresizing masks on your different UI elements. For example, I think the *Start* label is anchored to the top of the view, whereas the image(?) below it is anchored to the bottom of the view.

Comment: Hmm to be honest, I'm not sure myself. Is there anyway to 'unanchored' the objects? and reset the sizes? thanks

Comment: In IB, select the layout inspector (where you can set the frame). There's a UI element in here for setting autoresizing masks.

Comment: On autoresizing where you can click the red arrows? I've clicked all the red arrows but this hasn't solved the problem. Every object which i set still moved 2mm up

Comment: You need to anchor those elements to the bottom of the screen, bottom Red I shape only, no arrows.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but creating a whole new view within the xib. The problem still persists. I click on an object, go to size inspector. And the I's are already red?

Comment: If you can add a screenshot of your whole view with one of these elements selected (so I can see the autoresizing mask) it would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, here is the screenshot. This is of the UISwitch http://i.imgur.com/pcWQ4.png

Comment: Right I see your problem, it should only be the bottom I shape that is highlighted, remove the other ones.